# Google maps my location and way on my work street

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var my={directionsSVC:new google.maps.DirectionsService(),maps:{},routes:{}};
    /**
        * base-class
        * @param points optional array array of lat+lng-values defining a route
        * @return object Route
    **/
    function Route(points) {
        this.origin       = null;
        this.destination  = null;
        this.waypoints    = [];
        if(points && points.length>1) { this.setPoints(points);}
        return this;
    };

    /**
        *  draws route on a map
        *
        * @param map object google.maps.Map
        * @return object Route
    **/
    Route.prototype.drawRoute = function(map) {
        var _this=this;
        my.directionsSVC.route(
          {"origin": this.origin,
           "destination": this.destination,
           "waypoints": this.waypoints,
           "travelMode": google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
          },
          function(res,sts) {
                if(sts==google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK){
                    if(!_this.directionsRenderer) { _this.directionsRenderer=new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({ "draggable":true }); }
                    _this.directionsRenderer.setMap(map);
                    _this.directionsRenderer.setDirections(res);
                    google.maps.event.addListener(_this.directionsRenderer,"directions_changed", function() { _this.setPoints(); } );
                }
          });
        return _this;
    };

    /**
    * sets map for directionsRenderer
    * @param map object google.maps.Map
    **/
    Route.prototype.setGMap = function(map){ this.directionsRenderer.setMap(map); };

    /**
    * sets origin, destination and waypoints for a route
    * from a directionsResult or the points-param when passed
    *
    * @param points optional array array of lat+lng-values defining a route
    * @return object Route
    **/
    Route.prototype.setPoints = function(points) {
        this.origin = null;
        this.destination = null;
        this.waypoints = [];
        if(points) {
          for(var p=0;p<points.length;++p){
            this.waypoints.push({location:new google.maps.LatLng(points[p][0], points[p][1]),stopover:false});
          }
          this.origin=this.waypoints.shift().location;
          this.destination=this.waypoints.pop().location;
        }
        else {
          var route=this.directionsRenderer.getDirections().routes[0];
          for(var l=0;l<route.legs.length;++l) {
            if(!this.origin)this.origin=route.legs[l].start_location;
            this.destination = route.legs[l].end_location;

            for(var w=0;w<route.legs[l].via_waypoints.length;++w) { this.waypoints.push({location:route.legs[l].via_waypoints[w], stopover:false});}
          }
          //the route has been modified by the user when you are here you may call now this.getPoints() and work with the result
        }
        return this;
    };

    /**
    * retrieves points for a route
    *
    * @return array
    **/
    Route.prototype.getPoints = function() {
      var points=[[this.origin.lat(),this.origin.lng()]];

      for(var w=0;w<this.waypoints.length;++w) { points.push([this.waypoints[w].location.lat(), this.waypoints[w].location.lng()]);}
      points.push([this.destination.lat(), this.destination.lng()]);
      return points;
    };

    function getLocation() {
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      } else {
        alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
      }
    }
    function showPosition(position) {
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      var lng = position.coords.longitude;
      map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
    }

    function initialize() {
      var myOptions = { zoom: 8, center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644), mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };
        my.maps.map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        my.routes.r0 = new Route([[55.930385, -3.118425],[50.909700, -1.40435]]).drawRoute(my.maps.map1);

        my.routes.rx=new Route();
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
</script>

<div id="map_canvas" style="height:300px;width:300px;"></div>
```

Im want pave the way from my point to point my work, how I can do it? I have getLocation() and showPosition() and I don't know how I can apply these functions on my code. Please help decide it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the problem is the asynchronic character of javascript.  It takes some time to execute functionality.

The javascript solution is the callback.  You tell a function: when you're done; execute this function; you feed that function to a parameter.

- google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize) means: when the window (page) is loaded, execute the initialize function.
- navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition); means: when you (javascript) find the user position, execute showPosition.

For Google Maps, I would advice this: first you show a default map center, default zoom; then if a user location is found, you pan (and maybe zoom) to that location.
So something like this (notice: the code looks like it executes the bottom part first, top part last; this is because you first want to decrare the functions, before you use them):

```
<script>
...

function showPosition(position) {
  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lng = position.coords.longitude;      
  map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
}

function getLocation() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  } 
  else {
    //alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
  }
}

function initialize() {
  // make the map
  var myOptions = { zoom: 8, center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644), ...}
  ...
  // now ask for the user location
  getLocation();
}

// page is loaded
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
</script>
```

---

I agree with el solo lobo.  It's better to build up a map from a simple example, then add components and functionality; than it is to reverse engineer complex code.  The reasons why they do some things, might not be relevant to the code you need.